# hide legend in qtm spatial plots from tmap package

Tags: r, tmap

can someone please tell me how to hide the legend in qtm spatial plots from tmap package with a polygon map of subcatchments (sc_p) clustered by Climate Class (CClass). I want to plot the map with a different colour for each of the 25 Climate Classes.

I have used:

```
library(tmap)
qtm(shp = sc_p, fill = "CClass", fill.n = 25)
```

I have tried `legend.show=FALSE` which makes no change to output and
`tm_layout(legend.show=FALSE)` which triggered an error message:

```
Error: symbol sizes are neither numeric nor valid variable name(s)
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: post your code perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this after your `qtm(...)` for hiding legend: `+ tm_legend(show=FALSE)`